# How to use IValidatableObject on Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, viewmodel, partial-views, ivalidatableobject

I can't seem to figure out **how to validate the pieces of a partial view for an ViewModel that has the partial ViewModel as a child object**. Here's my lowest level piece, which will ALWAYS be consumed as a partial view inside other form tags:

```
namespace MVC3App.ViewModels
{
    public class Payment : IValidatableObject
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public int CreditCardNumber { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Amount < 20)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please pay more than $20", new string[] { "Amount" });
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the 'main' ViewModel that includes it:

```
namespace MVC3App.ViewModels
{
    public class NewCustomerWithPayment :IValidatableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public ViewModels.Payment PaymentInfo { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Age < 18)
                yield return new ValidationResult("Too young.", new string[] { "Age" });
        }
    }
}
```

For the View of the NewCustomerWithPayment, I have this:

```
@model MVC3App.ViewModels.NewCustomerWithPayment
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>NewCustomerWithPayment</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    @Html.Partial("Payment")
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
}
```

And the Partial View "Payment" is ALWAYS rendered inside another Html.Beginform tag, it just has this:

```
@model MVC3App.ViewModels.Payment
<h2>Payment</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Payment</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditCardNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCardNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreditCardNumber)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**My problem is that I cannot get the Validation on the 'Payment' viewmodel to work. Can anyone with experience using IValidatableObject on ViewModels which are rendered as Partial Views chime in and give me a validation pattern that works? I can live without JavaScript validation if I have to.**

Comment: I don't mean for this to sound sarcastic, but it from the code you've posted, it appears that you are only performing very basic validation on an int (Age) and a decimal (Amount).  This is well within the capabilities of data annotations.  Why are you writing your own and not using what's built into the framework?

Comment: The example code is simplified. The actual validation calls will talk to data sources and such.

Answer (score 1):

These answers all have some great info, but my immediate issue was resolved by using this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentInfo)
```

Instead of this:

```
Html.Partial("Payment", Model.PaymentInfo)
```

I was surprised that this worked, but it does. **The EditorFor helper renders out the partial view just like Html.Partial, and wires in the validation automatically.** For some reason, it does call the validation twice on the child model (Payment in my example), which seems to be a reported issue for some other people (http://mvcextensions.codeplex.com/workitem/10), so I have to include a boolean for 'HasBeenValidated' on each model and check for it at the beginning of the Validate call.

**Update:** you must move your view to the EditorTemplates folder under /Views/Shared/ in order for the view to be used by the EditorFor helper. Otherwise, the EditorFor will give you the default editing fields for the types.

Comment: I had no idea that EditorFor would do that.  Good to know, as this is a pretty common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lame example of a custom validator for a checkbox :) I would write a custom validator or use a regex maybe. This may get you on the right path and be easier.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class CheckBoxMustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    #region IClientValidatable Members

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
                                                                           ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
                         {
                             ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                             ValidationType = "requiredcheckbox"
                         };
    }

    #endregion

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return (bool) value;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `IValidatableObject` is recognized only on the root model. You can call the inner model `Validate` method from the root model:

```
public class NewCustomerWithPayment :IValidatableObject {
   ...
   public ViewModels.Payment PaymentInfo { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      if (Age < 18)
         yield return new ValidationResult("Too young.", new string[] { "Age" });

      if (this.PaymentInfo != null)
         yield return this.PaymentInfo.Validate(validationContext);
   }
}
```

Note: Not sure if the above compiles.